# Remove space after pages (pp.) in .bst files

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, errors, custom-bib

There is an unecessary space after pp. in my references that I am trying to get rid of. I managed to find where they are in the bst file, but every time I remove `tie.or.space.prefix` an error occurs.

```
FUNCTION {format.pages}
{ pages duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    { duplicate$ multi.page.check
        {
          bbl.pages swap$
          n.dashify
        }
        {
          bbl.page swap$
        }
      if$
      tie.or.space.prefix
      "pages" bibinfo.check
      * *
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.journal.pages}
{ pages duplicate$ empty$ 'pop$
    { swap$ duplicate$ empty$
        { pop$ pop$ format.pages }
        {
          ", " *
          swap$
          n.dashify
          pages multi.page.check
            'bbl.pages
            'bbl.page
          if$
          swap$ tie.or.space.prefix
          "pages" bibinfo.check
          * *
          *
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
```

Comment: The space after “pp.” is typographically correct.

Comment: @egreg not according to them: https://libweb.anglia.ac.uk/referencing/harvard.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very difficult to create working code from a fragment of a `.bst` file with no other information.  So this is an educated guess.

Instead of `tie.or.space.prefix` before the `"pages"` lines in the rest of the `.bst` file, use the following:

```
""
```

Comment: Please remove $swap so I can mark your answer accepted. Thanks.

Comment: @user5482015 Ok. But it would have been helpful to post (a link to) the whole `.bst` file for testing purposes and also show a minimal document using it.

Comment: I will do it next time. It is a standard cardiff file.